# R output multiple row values that belong to minimum of group and compare the values in case_when

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

#### Dataset

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E"), 
             Encounter = c(10, 11, 12, 3, 5, 50, 8, 8, 15, 20, 2, 8, 10), 
             Item = c("apple", "toy", "bowl", "apple", "mango", "mango", "toy", "brush", "toy", "brush", "brush", "key", "key"))

# A tibble: 13 x 3
   ID    Encounter Item 
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
 1 A            10 apple
 2 A            11 toy  
 3 A            12 bowl 
 4 B             3 apple
 5 C             5 mango
 6 C            50 mango
 7 D             8 toy  
 8 D             8 brush
 9 D            15 toy  
10 D            20 brush
11 E             2 brush
12 E             8 key  
13 E            10 key
```

#### Criteria

I wish to find out if the `Item` in the first `Encounter` appears in the subsequent `Encounter`.

1. For example, in `A`, the `Item` in the first `Encounter` is `apple`, which does not appear in subsequent `Encounter` therefore the output should be `FALSE`.
2. For example, in `C`, `mango` does appear in subsequent `Encounter`, therefore the output should be `TRUE`
3. For example, in `D`, both `toy` and `brush` are in the first `Encounter`, and they both appears in the subsequent `Encounter`, therefore the output should be `TRUE`
4. The `Item` in the first `Encounter` should always be `FALSE`.

#### Desired output

Here is my desired output for your better understanding:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
   ID    Encounter Item  Output
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <lgl> 
 1 A            10 apple FALSE 
 2 A            11 toy   FALSE 
 3 A            12 bowl  FALSE 
 4 B             3 apple FALSE 
 5 C             5 mango FALSE 
 6 C            50 mango TRUE  
 7 D             8 toy   FALSE 
 8 D             8 brush FALSE 
 9 D            15 toy   TRUE  
10 D            20 brush TRUE  
11 E             2 brush FALSE 
12 E             8 key   FALSE 
13 E            10 key   FALSE
```

#### My attempt

I have used `dplyr::case_when()`

1. to set the row of min `Encounter` to `FALSE` **(successful)**
2. to set `Item` that is **NOT** in the first `Encounter` **(successful)**
3. to set `Item` that **IS** in the first `Encounter` **(FAILED if there are multiple `Item`s in first `Encounter`)**

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Encounter) %>% 
  mutate(Output = case_when(Encounter == min(Encounter) ~ F, 
                            Item %in% first(Item) ~ T, 
                            !(Item %in% first(Item)) ~ F))

# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   ID [5]
   ID    Encounter Item  Output
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <lgl> 
 1 A            10 apple FALSE 
 2 A            11 toy   FALSE 
 3 A            12 bowl  FALSE 
 4 B             3 apple FALSE 
 5 C             5 mango FALSE 
 6 C            50 mango TRUE  
 7 D             8 toy   FALSE 
 8 D             8 brush FALSE 
 9 D            15 toy   TRUE  
10 D            20 brush FALSE 
11 E             2 brush FALSE 
12 E             8 key   FALSE 
13 E            10 key   FALSE
```

#### Ultimate question

Is there any function that acts like `dplyr::first()`, but able to return multiple values that can be used in the `case_when()` function or `ifelse()`?

For example in `D`, I don't know how to output both `toy` and `brush` so that it can be compared using `%in%`.

Sorry for the long question, hope someone can help!

Also, feels like my `case_when()` expression is not written in a smart way, please feel free to leave a comment if you have suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `duplicated` - the values in 'Encounter' are already `arrange`d, if not, do an `arrange(ID, Encounter)` before the `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(Output =   first(Item) %in% Item[-1] & duplicated(Item)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 × 4
   ID    Encounter Item  Output
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <lgl> 
 1 A            10 apple FALSE 
 2 A            11 toy   FALSE 
 3 A            12 bowl  FALSE 
 4 B             3 apple FALSE 
 5 C             5 mango FALSE 
 6 C            50 mango TRUE  
 7 D             8 toy   FALSE 
 8 D             8 brush FALSE 
 9 D            15 toy   TRUE  
10 D            20 brush TRUE  
11 E             2 brush FALSE 
12 E             8 key   FALSE 
13 E            10 key   FALSE
```